# How to Divide IST Date to Normal Date in Java Code?

Tags: java, date

My Date is coming with IST standing i.e 5:30 ITS like this
I don't want my date like this.

My code is like,

I have one class name is  Example.In this class I have a variable

```
public class Example {
private Date date;
 |
 |
```

}

I have another Javmail class here I have one metod to send email to one user.

```
 public class JavaMail implements Runnable {

public static void sendEmailForProfileActivation(Example ex){

LogMsg.info("example date:"ex.getDate());

 }

}
```

Here from client side they are sending date in the IST format like,

```
  Fri Sep 25 05:30:00 IST 2015
```

I dont want 05:30:00 IST ,I need Fri Sep 25 2015.

Can any boyd help me in this,

Thanks in Advance,

MadanMohan

Comment: Are you getting the date object or date string? If date string then get the substring till before the IST part.

Comment: i am getting date object

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want 05:30:00 IST ,I need Fri Sep 25 2015.

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy");
Date d1 = parser.parse("Fri Sep 25 05:30:00 IST 2015");
SimpleDateFormat parser1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy");
System.out.println(parser1.format(d1));
```

**Output:**

```
Fri Sep 25 2015
```

Comment: my date type is not string format it is in date format.

Comment: @MadanMohan so look last two lines.

Comment: I have completed this one.If any body got Struckked from this ping me.I will give a response to you.